# Android Studio error when viewing SDK source

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2, there are many "cannot resolve method" errors in Android SDK source files:

[image]

Unlike other similar questions on SO, such errors do not appear in my own code, but only in Android SDK source files.

Although my project can compile, they are still very annoying as I cannot Ctrl-Click to track down these methods.

Can anyone give some advice about this ?

Additionally, my project is targeting Android SDK level 23 and using JDK 1.7.

Comment: I have encountered this problem. It seems that the Android 23 sources compile against an older SDK, perhaps 21, and uses methods that are not present in SDK 23.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

jummm that is really weird behaviour, try cleaning and rebuilding the project, and also please try to check that there are no mistakes inside the build.gradle application files. Please also put your log error just to see what is going on

Comment: Try to click File --> Invalidate Cache/Restart --> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Why would there be log errors? The post said the project can compile...

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the File --> Invalidate Cache/Restart --> Invalidate and Restart thing, that @sonnv1368 mentioned. The errors were gone first and the navigation keys worked again. However Android Studio run a task right after the restart, which said "Context: Indexing...". After that was finished, the errors occured again and the navigation keys did not work anymore. When trying to go to a declaration it always says "Cannot find declaration to go to". That worked fine directly after the restart and before finishing the indexing.